# Prove $ A^2 = 2A $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have the following question in my linear algebra textbook:

> Let $ A, B \in M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{F}) $ such that $ A(B - I) = A $ and $ B(A - I) = B $. Prove that $ A^2 = 2A $.

---

Here is what I have so far:

$$ A(B - I) = A \Rightarrow AB - A = A \Rightarrow AB = 2A $$

I understand now that I have to prove $ A^2 = AB $, but I have no idea how to continue, could you please give me a clue?

Comment: $A(B-I)=A=A\cdot I\Rightarrow B=2I; B(A-I)=B=B\cdot I\Rightarrow A=2I; A^2=A$.

Comment: Which textbook?

Comment: @WindSoul:  I presume you meant $A^2=\color{red}2A$

Comment: @WindSoul, your argument doesn't work since $A$ and $B$ are not assumed to be invertible. For example, $A=B=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 2 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$ satisfy hypothesis. Or $A=B = 0$.

Comment: True and true. Thank you.

Comment: All provided answers rely on the fact that $2\ne0$; I'm wondering if the result still holds when $\mathop{\rm char}(\Bbb{F})=2$. In which case the question becomes: $(AB=BA=0)\ \stackrel{?}{\Longrightarrow}\ (A^2=0)$.

Comment: Answering my own question… $A=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ and $B=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$,we have $AB=BA=0$ but $A^2=A\ne0$; the hypothesis $\mathop{\rm char}(\Bbb{F})\ne2$ is hence necessary.

Answer (score 5):

Since $AB = 2A$ and $BA = 2B$,
$$
2 A^2 = (AB)A = A(BA) = 2AB = 4A.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the first equation:

$A(B-I) = A$

Distribute $A$:

$AB - A = A$

Add $A$ to both sides:

$AB = 2A$

Now, using the second equation:

$B(A-I) = B$

Distribute $B$:

$BA - B = B$

Add $B$ to both sides:

$BA = 2B$

Let's substitute the expression we found for $BA$ into the equation we found for $AB$:

$AB = 2A$

$(2B)A = 2A$

Simplify:

$BA = A$

Substitute this expression for $BA$ in the previous equation:

$AB = 2A$

$A(BA) = 2A$

$A^2 = 2A$

So we have shown that $A^2 = 2A$, as required.

Answer (score 1):

Since $AB=2A$ and $BA=2B$,
$$
A^2=\frac{AB}2A=A\frac{BA}2=AB=2A.
$$